# Need program to wait until button is clicked in another class

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Need Start() to wait until button is clicked in another class before continuing. Please help.

Cricket Match

```
private string occurance;

public void Start()
{
    EnterGUI objE = new EnterGUI();

    objE.setVisible(true);

    String occur = objE.textField.getText();

    occurance = occur;
}
```

EnterGUI

```
public class EnterGUI extends JFrame {

    String occurance;

    public void setOccurance(String occurance) {
        this.occurance = occurance;
    }

    public String getOccurance() {
        return occurance;
    }

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("Save");
    btnNewButton.setBounds(120, 5, 86, 43);
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        setOccurance(textField.getText());
    }
  });
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Why do you need to wait? Call start() when the button is clicked...

```
btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
      setOccurance(textField.getText());

      CricketMatch cricketMatch = new CricketMatch();
      cricketMatch.start();
   }
});
```

BTW, methods should begin with a small letter.